# Stopping function after exception

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues with creating an error handling method. After encountering an error, the sub continues as if nothing happened. This is what I have:

```
try 
{
    int numericID = Convert.ToInt32(titleID);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    errorHandling("Invalid Title");
}

void errorHandling(string error)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have encountered an error: " + error, "Error");
    return;
}
```

Comment: You catch the exception, then call another method. If you don't want to continue you should either return or rethrow the exception after calling `errorHandling`.

Comment: That's what happens when you catch and handle an exception. Don't wrap methods in try catch blocks if you want them to throw exceptions and break the program.

Comment: OK, you catched the exception, handled it by showing the error message. What do you want to do next. Your code doesn't show anything about it.

Comment: `After encountering an error, the sub continues as if nothing happened.` that's what you asked it to do. You caught the error and handled it. If you want the error to continue to propagate, just `throw` it again in your `catch` block (after the call to `errorHandling`).

Comment: I just wanted to stop the function and completely and let the user interact with the form again. Previously I figured return would do that but I'm mistaken.

Comment: You might want to check out `Int32.TryParse` to avoid the exception all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try 
    {
        int numericID = Convert.ToInt32(titleID);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        errorHandling("Invalid Title");
        return; // <---- perhaps you wanted to put the return here?
    }

void errorHandling(string error)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have encountered an error: " + error, "Error");
    // return; <-- does nothing
}
```

Is it code in other functions which you want to hault execution of when exception is caught? Just make a global boolean:

```
bool exceptionCaught = false;

....

try 
    {
        int numericID = Convert.ToInt32(titleID);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        errorHandling("Invalid Title");
        exceptionCaught = true;
        return; // <---- perhaps you wanted to put the return here?
    }

void errorHandling(string error)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have encountered an error: " + error, "Error");
    // return; <-- does nothing
}

....

void OtherMethod()
{
    if(!exceptionCaught)
    {
        // All other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still allowing the code to execute after running into the error. If I have more code that needs to be run after the try catch statement, I'd like it only to be can if no exception is thrown. If there is an exception, the code exits and allows the user to re-interact with the form.                                                       Edit: Ah, I see that return will exit the cuttent method but if the try catch statement is called from a secondary method, I have to use return twice. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What do you *want* to happen?

Some common things are bubbling up the exception...

```
    try 
    {
        int numericID = Convert.ToInt32(titleID);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        errorHandling("Invalid Title");

        // rethrow the error after you handle it
        //
        throw;
    }
```

Or you could log the error in your `errorHandling()` method.

Or you can `return` from your parent method where the exception was thrown.

Either way, you're `catch`ing the exception, and you're executing `errorHandling()` method, but at that point the `catch` block is done with its execution... *so code continues*.

Whatever you want to happen... ***make it happen in the catch block, or you're just silencing errors***.  If you don't want execution to continue, then don't allow execution to continue, but you need to explicitly write the code for that in the `catch` block.

Comment: After catching the error, I'd like to display it to the user (errorHandling) and then stop the code completely allowing the user to interact with the form again and fix the issue causing the error.

Comment: @MasonHanson Then you'd just want to "return" either at the end of the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement at the end of your `errorHandling` method does not terminate the program. To terminate you need to call Application.Exit or System.Environment.Exit depending on the type of your application

Answer (score -1):

You're calling a method after you catch the exception. If you want to program to end, you need to either rethrow the exception after you call errorHandling, or call `System.Environment.Exit(1);` to end the program.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you add a break; to the exception, it may fix your issue. Or you may also try using a throw.